# Path variable issue in cmd commands and java commands

Tags: java, cmd, path-variables

When I set path `C:\Windows\System32`, the `ipconfig` command works, but `javac` and `java -version` commands don't work.

While, when I set path variable to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1\bin` they work, but `ipconfig` command stops working.

How can I solve it in order to make work both the commands?

Comment: what path are you setting?

Comment: your c:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1\bin isn't in your PATH

Comment: Your path should contain multiple directories.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO.

You can extend your PATH variable with additional directories instead of replacing it.

See also: [Adding a directory to the PATH environment variable in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-a-directory-to-the-path-environment-variable-in-windows)

Comment: Thanks for your response,i tried adding path1 C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1\bin and path2 C:\Windows\System32 it is working now .Is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

Add both the folders to path variable seperated by ';'
eg

```
PATH1;PATH2
```

Comment: thanks for your response ,i tried doing it but it didn't work ,i tried adding path1 C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1\bin and path2 C:\Windows\System32 it is working now .Is it correct?

Comment: you need to set  your path variable to 
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1\bin;C:\Windows\System32